# How do you create a hash table in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, dictionary, hashtable

I am creating a simple hash table in VS 2008 C++.

```
#include <map>
std::map <string, char> grade_list;
grade_list["John"] = 'B';
```

I am getting the error:
error C2057: expected constant expression

What does that mean? Does boost library have something better?

Thanks!

Comment: For a tiny program, you have posted something that's not even likely to compile for lack of a main function, and missing headers like <string>

Comment: @Vatsan - That was the problem. I didn't put that code in the main function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, char> grade_list;
    grade_list["John"] = 'B';
    std::cout << grade_list["John"] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This works great with g++.
You should specify std:: before string in your map declaration, as I did in my code.

Answer (score 10):

First of all `std::map` is a treemap, not a hashmap.

The reason you get the error is that you did not `#include <string>` nor qualify the reference to `string` and thus the compiler does not know that `string` is a class.

Comment: <unordered_map> is coming in C++0x.

Comment: OK, so how do you create a hash table?

Comment: @BSeven: By using a compiler that already implements C++0x's unordered_map (recent versions of gcc and visual studio do) and using that or by using [boost's implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/unordered.html).

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I didn't know what it was called. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code was before main function.